# python3 print format output

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

In python3 , if I have a list[a,b,c], how can I print the output such as :

```
results: a 
         b
         c
```

but my output is like：

```
results: a
b
c
```

My code is

```
List = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print（"results :", end = " ")
for i in List:
  print(i)
```

How can I format it?

Answer (score 1):

Add padding for the lines after the first line:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
pad = len('results:') * ' '  # Number of spaces to insert (2nd, 3rd, ... lines)
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if i == 0:
        print('results:', x)
    else:
        print(pad, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `format()`:

```
List = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print("results :", end = " ")
for i, e in enumerate(List):
    if (i == 0):
        print (e)
    else:
        print ("{:>{}}".format(e, len("results :  ")))
```